# Installing iPython: "ImportError cannot import name path"?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm trying to install IPython. I have run `pip install ipython[notebook]` without any errors, but now I get this:

```
$ ipython notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/.venv/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 16, in <module>
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pickleshare import PickleShareDB
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pickleshare.py", line 41, in <module>
    from path import path as Path
ImportError: cannot import name path
```

I have the same error if I try to run `import pickleshare` at a Python console, or `from path import path`.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You don't have a path.py file somewhere in your path?

Comment: Actually is this a dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252915/error-running-a-fresh-install-of-ipython?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/pickleshare/pickleshare/issues/8), caused by a change in the `path.py` package. Reverting to an older version of `path.py` solves this :

```
sudo pip3 install -I path.py==7.7.1
```

Answer (score 4):

It appears that `pickleshare` is in package `IPython.utils`. Try tying

```
from IPython.utils.pickleshare import PickleShareDB
```

Similarly, `path` is in `IPython.external`. Try typing

```
from IPython.external.path import path as Path
```

In either case, I would check if following files exist.

```
"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/pickleshare.py"
"/Users/me/.virtualenvs/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/external/path/_path.py"
```

All this points to the fact that probably your IPython/notebook version is old. A couple of solutions would be

1) Try editing files in site-packages and changing import lines to

```
from IPython.external.path import path as Path
from IPython.utils.pickleshare import PickleShareDB
```

But that's kind of risky, who knows what else might fail.

Otherwise, try upgrading ipython/notebook

```
pip install ipython --upgrade
pip install "ipython[notebook]" --upgrade
```

Comment: Just "pip install ipython --upgrade" was my solution.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issues and rolling back to an earlier version of `path.py` did not not help. I uninstalled the package and then IPython Notebook worked.

`pip uninstall -y path.py`

Answer (score 1):

import Path (not path - It should be "UPPER CASE" P and not "lower case" p)

Answer (score 0):

I received this error while trying to import matplotlib on Windows 10. My problem was that matplotlib needed an update. I just ran the following code:

```
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

or:

```
conda install matplotlib
```

My guess is that this can be applied to IPython.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, use :
`from pathlib import Path`