# Error running a fresh install of iPython

Tags: python, ipython

I am using virtualenvwrapper so anybody can reproduce it easily, but this happens as well using `pip` directly on my system.

After installing iPython with `pip`, I wont be able to run it (note I'm using the Python 2 interpreter, although the same exact thing will happen if I use Python 3):

```
$ mkvirtualenv -p python2 test
$ pip install --upgrade pip      # Just in case...
$ pip install ipython
$ ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peque/.virtualenvs/test/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/home/peque/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/home/peque/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 16, in <module>
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod
  File "/home/peque/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pickleshare import PickleShareDB
  File "/home/peque/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pickleshare.py", line 41, in <module>
    from path import path as Path
ImportError: cannot import name path
```

Now, the packages I have installed after this simple steps are:

```
$ pip freeze
decorator==4.0.2
ipython==4.0.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
path.py==8.0
pexpect==3.3
pickleshare==0.5
simplegeneric==0.8.1
traitlets==4.0.0
```

Why am I getting this error? Is there any way to avoid it while still using iPython version 4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Quick fix

Just downgrade package:

```
pip install -I path.py==7.7.1
```

### Explanation

There is a [commit (62ccb76)](https://github.com/jaraco/path.py/commit/62ccb7623d4d048af663f205e21c2ec3f24fa17d) made a couple of hours ago that removes the `path` alias and bumps `path.py` version to `0.8`. Apparently, in order to fix [Issue #102](https://github.com/jaraco/path.py/issues/102):

> Removed `path.path`. Clients must now refer to the canonical name, `path.Path` as introduced in 6.2.

However, `pickleshare` has not been updated and continues to use the old alias.

The problem [has already been reported](https://github.com/pickleshare/pickleshare/issues/8), and hope it will be fixed soon. I created [a pull request](https://github.com/pickleshare/pickleshare/pull/9) in case it helps.

### Update

The pull request has already been merged and [version 8.1 of `path.py` adds the `path` alias again](https://github.com/jaraco/path.py/commit/3520e8f143a8ded9d5fa8e66038c1db3e75b112a) (a warning will be generated instead for now). So users should not hit this problem now.

Updating the package to version `8.1` should fix the problem as well now:

```
pip install -I path.py==8.1
```

Comment: Another quick fix is to modify `".../python2.7/site-packages/pickleshare.py", line 41` to read `from path import Path` instead of `from path import path as Path` as [shown in OP's PR](https://github.com/pickleshare/pickleshare/pull/9/files)

Answer (score 2):

Your import looks incorrect, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/path.py

```
from path import Path
```

Comment: Not mine, but `pickleshare`'s. Thank you.

Comment: [I added an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32254055/3577054) with a fix and more information about this bug.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an Ipython installed system wide. Just run `workon test` before starting ipython.

Comment: I do not have iPython installed system wide, and of course I'm working on the virtual environment (`mkvirtualenv` will automatically load it after creating it).

Comment: You would think that, but I often encounter the situation where I have to workon again, to get the local ipython instead of the system one.

Comment: Well, I think this is not the case. Deactivating and activating it again yields the same result as expected. ;-)