# PyQt_Fit: cannot import name path

Tags: python

I'm trying to use PyQt_Fit. I installed it from pip install pyqt_fit but when I import it does not work and show me this message:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                           Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-8-36ec621967a7> in <module>()
----> 1 import pyqt_fit

/home/yuri/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyqt_fit/__init__.py in <module>()
     12            'functions', 'residuals', 'CurveFitting']
     13 
---> 14 from . import functions
     15 from . import residuals
     16 from .curve_fitting import CurveFitting

/home/yuri/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyqt_fit/functions/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 
      5 from ..utils import namedtuple
----> 6 from .. import loader
      7 import os
      8 from path import path

/home/yuri/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyqt_fit/loader.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import print_function, absolute_import
      2 import inspect
----> 3 from path import path
      4 import imp
      5 import sys

ImportError: cannot import name path
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing iPython: "ImportError cannot import name path"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252122/installing-ipython-importerror-cannot-import-name-path)

Comment: Actually Im not trying to install iPython. I've tried to make all the things showed on that post, but it did not work. My doubt is about PyQt_Fit, which also happened in others computer.

Comment: Do not pay attention to that detail, but to the main problem.

Comment: I tried all the 3 suggestion and it still not working.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem with you. when I install the pyqt_fit package successfully by

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/Multiplicom/pyqt-fit.git
```

It will install the path.py (The last version) and pyqt_fit at the same time.

Then When I import the package, I faced the follow error

```
import pyqt_fit
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-253-36ec621967a7>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyqt_fit

  File "/Users/mengxinpan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyqt_fit/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import functions, residuals

  File "/Users/mengxinpan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyqt_fit/residuals/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from path import path

ImportError: cannot import name 'path'
```

The error is caused by the path.path function has been revised to path.Path in the last version path.py package.

So my solution is open all the file in the pyqt_fit folder, like 'site-packages/pyqt_fit/residuals/**init**.py', change all the

```
from path import path
```

to

```
from path import Path as path
```

Then I can import the pyqt_fit successfully.

I try to install the old version path.py by

```
sudo pip install -I path.py==7.7.1
```

But it still not working.

Answer (score 2):

Although people are suggesting `path.py==7.7.1`, it worked with `path.py=7.1` for me:

```
sudo pip uninstall -y path.py
sudo pip install -I path.py==7.1
```

I'm also using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be happening for quite some time. Check this recent issue report [on the repo](https://github.com/sergeyfarin/pyqt-fit/issues/5).

I've installed the package and tested myself and I got the same problem. Checked the solution provided on the possible duplicate and seems to have fixed the problem.

You might not have pip3 installed, so try with:

```
sudo pip install -I path.py==7.7.1
```

Edit:

You can also try installing the package directly from [this forked repo](https://github.com/Multiplicom/pyqt-fit/pull/1) that seems to have fixed it:

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/Multiplicom/pyqt-fit.git
```

Comment: Still not working.
I've made just like you've said and still appears the same error.